# AWS SSM Python / Boto3 Create Hybrid Activation ExpirationDate Type Error

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-systems-manager

I am trying to create AWS SSM Hybrid activations for multiple divisions. My IDE is telling me that datetime is not callable, and the error message I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\bin\Create-Activation.py", line 23, in <module>
    ExpirationDate = datetime(y, m, d),
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

The variables y, m, and d are being passed to ExpirationDate object. I am using the Amazon and Boto3 documentation as a guide.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.create_activation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/SSM/Client.html#create_activation-instance_method

Can someone help me understand why the ExpirationDate object is failing?

```
import boto3
import datetime

client = boto3.client('ssm')
current_date = datetime.date.today()
creation_date = current_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
end_date = current_date + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
y = end_date.year
m = end_date.month
d = end_date.day
divisions = ['div1', 'div2', 'div3']

#def lambda_handler(event, context):

for x in divisions:
    client.create_activation(
        Description = (x + '-' + 'creation_date'),
        #DefaultInstanceName = 'string',
        IamRole = 'MySSMServiceRole',
        RegistrationLimit = 200,
        ExpirationDate = datetime(y, m, d),
        Tags=[
            {
                'Key': 'Division',
                'Value': x
            },
        ]
    )
    print('\n ' + x + '-creation_date was create.')
```

Comment: Thank you for the update. This is what I'm getting after using `from datetime import datetime`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmoorhead\bin\Create-Activation.py", line 7, in <module>
    current_date = datetime.date.today()
AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'`

Comment: use `current_date = datetime.today()` . As I mentioned, use dir() to check the attributes of objects.

Comment: Thank you Saranjeet. I ended up using `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` and modifying a couple of my variables. The `print(dir(datetime))` was very useful in doing so.

Comment: Happy to help @jmoorhead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from datetime import datetime` instead of `import datetime`.
Datetime modules itself not callable, but you can call its attribute `datetime`.

Comment: you can use dir() function to list out all the attributes of datetime module. `print(dir(datetime))`